# Webpack: import `<name>.development.js` instead of `<name>.js` when bundling with `development` environment

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, environment

I've been googling this but I can't come up with any results, even though I'm fairly confident it's possible.

I have a `RootComponent.js` file which I want to extend with some extra functionality when webpack is building using the `development` environment. Therefore I'd like an import like:

```
import {RootComponent} from "./RootComponent.js";
```

to resolve to a file called `RootComponent.development.js` when the corresponding environment is set.

For all other environments, including production, I'd like the import to resolve to `RootComponent.js`.

I'd like this to happen automatically: if there's a `.development.js` file of the same name as the one being imported, I'd like webpack to give it precedence when the right environment is set.

How is this done?

Comment: although I don't use webpack, I remember you can write your own build script, I think you can change the lookup directory of those library.

Comment: I've done something similar by using aliases (for platform-specific builds), but it gets pretty unwieldy if there's more than a few files that you are treating this way. You could write your own plugin that could do something similar, but I think you also need to stop and consider that there may be a reason the tool is resisting you. Are you sure this is a good idea? If you have separate development and production code bases then you're more likely to have failures in your production environment.